# What does "H St Aff" mean as an action taken on a proposed bill (Idaho)?

Tags: united-states, legislative-process, us-state-laws, state-legislatures

Idaho's legislature is in session. I've been monitoring their activity on [this page](https://legislature.idaho.gov/sessioninfo/2021/legislation/). I can usually tell what abbreviations for actions taken on bills mean at a glance, but this one has me stumped:

```
H0001       Disasters, governor’s powers        H St Aff    *
                                                ^^^^^^^^
```

From looking at an [older session](https://legislature.idaho.gov/sessioninfo/2005/legislation/), I see many abbreviations that look like (H)ouse committees - i.e. "H Rev/Tax", "H Transp", etc. So I suspect this indicates a committee, but the name of it is eluding me (and [Google isn't very helpful](https://www.google.com/search?q=idaho+legislature+h+st+aff)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clicking through on the [bill number](https://legislature.idaho.gov/sessioninfo/2021/legislation/H0001/) gives the unabbreviated version: "STATE AFFAIRS COMMITTEE"

Answer (score 1):

Just after posting this (of course), I found a [list of House committees](https://legislature.idaho.gov/sessioninfo/agenda/). It's now obvious to me that "H St Aff" is the House **State Affairs** committee.